# Python... counting number of letters in the Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Now I Have a dataframe,

```
 please = pd.DataFrame({'name':['kitty', 'bake','kitty','bake'], 
                              'level' : ['12', '12', '15', '15'],
                              'col1':['......kkkkkkk......kkkkkkkkkkk.....kkkkkkkkkkkk', '......kkkkkkkkk.........kkkkkkk.......kkkkkkkk...', 'kkkk....kkkkkk....kkkkkkkkkkk......','kkkkkkk...kkkkkkkk.k.kkkkk........kk']})
```

and DataFrame like :

```
    name level                                               col1
0  kitty    12      ......kkkkkkk......kkkkkkkkkkk.....kkkkkkkkkkkk
1   bake    12  ......kkkkkkkkk.........kkkkkkk.......kkkkkkkk...
2  kitty    15                kkkk....kkkkkk....kkkkkkkkkkk......
3   bake    15               kkkkkkk...kkkkkkkk.k.kkkkkkkkkk........kk
```

*kitty, bake is just name, just meaningless word for DATAFRAME :)

#1st Question : i want to count [the number of   'k' block]. by making list. such like [7,8,1,10,2] : The example of 'index3'

```
bake_15 = [7,8,1,10,2]
```

#2nd Question : How can i ignore the under 5 in the list ?

```
bake_15_cut = [7,8,10]
```

#3rd Question : Want calculate kitty_level_12's 2nd number of 'k'block - bake_level_12's 2nd number of '.' block. I mean want to get the column 'level' information. I want code like :

```
result = please['col1_number'][(please['level'].str.contains('12', na=False) & (please['name'].str.contains('kitty', na=False))
```

Expected Result :

```
kitty_level_12_2nd 'k' block = 11
bake_level_12_2nd '.' block = 9
```

Comment: You already asked this previously. To filter the output: `out[out > 5]` if you have a Series, else `[x for x in out if x>5]`

Comment: `a = df['col1'].str.extractall('(k+)')[0].str.len().unstack('match', fill_value=0)`

Oh hi~ i  may use that code u gave. If i've use that code, `a[a>5]` will be the solution?

Comment: `please['col1'].str.extractall('(k+)')[0].str.len().loc[lambda x: x>5].groupby(level=0).agg(list)`

Comment: Oh, Your Code works. and Can i ask 2more question? I want make columns that take 2nd number of `please['col1'].str.extractall('(k+)')[0].str.len().loc[lambda x: x>5].groupby(level=0).agg(list)`  series Ex) [34, 54,1,17] into 54 as a float64.

Comment: add `.str[1]`, or replace `.groupby(level=0).agg(list)` with `.groupby(level=0).nth(1)`